# MapRoute in mixed web forms/MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, maproute

I have an older web-form app and now I am trying to add new pages using MVC.
It all seems to work just fine except one thing:
The application's default page (`login.aspx`) is a web form.
When user hit link `www.mysite.com`, instead of opening `www.mysite.com/login.aspx`, the site immediately goes to route specified in global.aspx as

```
routes.MapRoute("FrontLine", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "FrontLine", action = "QuickView", id = "" });
```

So, the question is how to make `login.aspx` a default page?
Is it possible to do without converting  `login.aspx` to a MVC view and adding corresponding controller?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:
excute line:
    routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "","~/Login.aspx") 
before calling
    routes.MapRoute